# Any equivalent of apex:variable in Lightning Components?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

In Visualforce [apex:variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm) can be used to avoid the repetition of a Visualforce expression.

I have a collection returned from an `@AuraEnabled` method for which I want to do the same sort of thing that `apex:variable` does:

```
<aura:iteration var="item" items="{! v.items }">
    <!-- aura:variable does not exist: is there a way to do this in Lightning? -->
    <aura:variable var="sob" value="{! item.reference.sobReference }"/>
    <tr>
        <td>{! sob.Name }</td>
        <td>{! sob.Birthdate }</td>
        ...
```

Is there a way to do this in Lightning Components?

Comment: The ever awkward `sob` reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You can use an attribute in the lightning component, and then set the value in your controller.

See

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_attribute.htm

and

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_attr_values.htm

Edit: It seems like you're just trying to alias an attribute you already have access to.

```
<aura:iteration var="item" items="{! v.items }">
<tr>
    <td>{! item.reference.sobReference.Name }</td>
    <td>{! item.reference.sobReference.Birthdate }</td>

    ...
```

Comment: Ross, I've tried various combinations of `aura:attribute` and `aura:set` (to assign the attribute inside the loop - don't see how to use the controller here) but none that I tried would save. Can you post a working example in your answer?

Comment: Yes I am trying to avoid the repetition of the common expression `.reference.sobReference` in the same way you would use a local variable in other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

The only pattern I've seen that works is to wrap your iteration in a custom `rowComponent` where attributes inside the row represent each of your nested expressions (for complicated objects).

So then you pass your `sob` in as a top level attribute and then break down each nested reference using something like `<aura:attribute name="sobName" default="{! v.sob.name }"/>`